# Using ng-selected in combobox return undefined in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem when ng-selected with the following code:

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="producto.proveedor">
     <option ng-selected="data.id_proveedor == proveedor.id" ng-repeat="proveedor in proveedores" value="{{proveedor}}">{{proveedor.nombre_empresa}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
app.controller("EditarProductoController", function editController($scope,$routeParams,$filter,$location){
    $scope.textButton = "Editar producto";
    $scope.producto = $filter('filter')($scope.productos, {id:$routeParams.id})[0];

    $scope.editarUsuario = function(){
        alert($scope.producto["proveedor"]);
        $location.url("/");
    }
```

})

If I remove "ng-selected" from the code, it works fine

The code works perfect, the problem is that when I load the form return in the value combobox "undefined", it is rare because the visual part works well, then I can solve the problem if I select a different item of the combobox and re-select the original, it is Very annoying to the client, does anyone know how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

While your post doesn't show it, I think the UI is being rendered before "productos" gets populated with data from the database, you could wait for the promise to end with ng-if

```
<div ng-if="productos">
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="producto.proveedor">
   <option ng-selected="data.id_proveedor == proveedor.id" ng-repeat="proveedor in proveedores" value="{{proveedor}}">{{proveedor.nombre_empresa}}
  </option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I already tried it and that's not the problem, I think it's an angular bug